# Trying to find the array with the largest first element?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the array with the largest first element, input would be

```
a = [[4.556, 20, 15], [4.772, 7, 4], [6.88, 5, 2], [2.33, 68, 9]]
```

output should be

```
[6.88,5,2]
```

because it has the largest first element

Answer (score 1):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) will automatically start with the first element of the arrays when comparing. All you need to do is:

```
a = [[4.556, 20, 15], [4.772, 7, 4], [6.88, 5, 2], [2.33, 68, 9]]
max(a)
# [6.88, 5, 2]
```

If the first elements are equal, it will compare the second, etc.. This process of comparison is described in the data [structure docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Comment: This could return different results from the max that uses only the first element. For example what happens if more than one list have the same value at the first position?

Comment: @DaniMesejo the behavior is well-defined in either case. The OP doesn't specify which they prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` parameter of [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
from operator import itemgetter
a = [[4.556, 20, 15], [4.772, 7, 4], [6.88, 5, 2], [2.33, 68, 9]]
result = max(a, key=itemgetter(0))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[6.88, 5, 2]
```

The [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function just fetches the first position of the list, for example:

```
itemgetter(0)([1, 2, 3])
```

returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @DaniMesejo's answer.

You can use `lambda` to save an import

```
max(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
```